# find list of all goldengate replicated tables

Tags: oracle, oracle-golden-gate

I want to be able to get a list of all tables being goldengate replicated (both extract and replicat tables) in a pdb. One way to get the list would be to go to params file and get the list, but there could be schema level replication enabled in which case I need to get the list of all tables. Is there any easy way such as querying any system tables to get that list?

DBA_LOG_GROUPS - this contains all tables on which supplemental logging is enabled but (a) not necessary there is active replication setup for it and (b) it can give me only extract tables - not replicat ones, right?

Answer (score 0):

you are asking for a list of all extract and replicat tables + schema level replication tables,
there is no such direct method to get that information.
I advise you to query that info:

```sql
select * from dba_tables where owner=YOUR_REPLICATED_SCHEMA
```

and manually adding them to the params file